# May I know how to write the logic for this in cognos report studio please?

Tags: cognos

I have to get an report with recent appointment date for the patient and also BP value from tha Vitals.
In the Vitals there are BP, rr, hr, height etc. But I have to only get the BP for the most recent appointment date. The BP value can be null or not null but I should get the recent appointment date. I am using meta data.

Comment: Are you using FM models, TM1 Cubes? Powerplay Cubes? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a Data item:
MAX([Appointment date] for [Patient])
or a filter:
[Appointment date]= MAX([Appointment date] for [Patient])

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Padmavthi!

maximum([BPU Date] for [Patient])

[image]

If the null results are getting tricky, try this:

Create a query for the BPU data and a query for the patients
Join the two queries with the following cardinality:

Patients 1.1 to 0.n BPU

[image]